# How to set file privileges based on database users

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, linux, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to create an html based file manager (in rails) with just basic functions (download, delete, upload) used by **groups** of clients/developers.

1. (How) Can i set a file to just be shown (readable) to a group of users (stored in database) only?
2. Is it an option to store the whole files (binary) in the database? Won't it create huge db?
3. Is there any way to solve this somehow with just directories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. http://boxroom.rubyforge.org/ is doing exactly what you describe. It is open source, so you might want to have a look at how they did.
2. Yes. Yes but you might judge it acceptable depending on the amount of data.
3. Yes. Coding that is possible.

Comment: thx Nicolas, this link was helpful. Btw, it didn't crossed my mind, that i can simply offer a file for download, without the file being in a public folder. So basically i just need to store filepaths and associate it with permissions in my model.